# Download a file through PHP

Tags: php, download, readfile

I'm trying to initiate a file download through PHP. It downloads, however, the file can't be opened. My path is correct because I did a test through previewing the image via the image tags in HTML.

```
    $findPage = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_id = '$pageId' LIMIT 1");
    $pg = mysql_fetch_array($findPage);

    $fullPath = $pg['page_link'];
    $explode = explode(".", $fullPath);

    $ext = $explode[count($explode)-1];

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="Name.'.$ext.'"');
    header('Content-type: image/'.$ext);
    readfile($fullPath);
```

Comment: You're 100% sure the file is not corrupted?

Comment: Try with http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: That code looks perfectly fine to me. Are you saving it in the correct file format? Have you tried downloading a different file with the same code?

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages. I do not see any kind of error checking in your code, it's not even properly indented, so I do not trust your words. BTW if it would be all true what you say, your script would work which it does not. So please review the issue your own and come up with additional error information. And testing via the IMG tag does not count, this is server-side, IMG tag is client.

Comment: And  I highly doubt you are storing the full path into the database if it worked outputting inside IMG tags SRC attribute. You might just mix URLs and file-paths on the server.

Comment: @navnav I used the same code with another page, still no dice.

Comment: just right before the `header()` calls, can you try adding this: `if (file_exists($fullPath)) echo 'Path is not the problem'; else echo 'Path is not fullPath and that is the problem!';` then run the script to see the output

Comment: @hakra Seeing that this is my first time ever doing a download script, I don't know what I would be checking for. It's odd that you don't trust my words mainly because it's indented improperly (plus the error checking was done in another script, what would I be checking for in a script like this? Maybe next time you could help me understand what I could do...?).

Comment: Thanks @rationalboss that's the type of error checking that can actually help me.

Comment: Path was not the problem @rationalboss. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you get if you try the following:

```
$fullPath = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

list($w,$h,$t) = getimagesize($fullPath);  
$mimetype = image_type_to_mime_type($t);
$extension = end(explode('.', $fullPath));

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="Name.'.$extension.'"');
header('Content-type: '.$mimetype);
readfile($fullPath);
```

You should get Google's logo downloading... I do on my local set-up.

*(this code will require fopen_wrappers enabled on your server)*

If you do get Google's logo downloading correctly then I would suggest it's either a problem with the data being served from your db, or a permissions problem when readfile tries to access and read your file.

```
file_exists( $fullPath ) /// will tell you if the file exists or not

is_readable( $fullPath ) /// could be useful to detect a read error
```

If you don't get Google's logo then either fopen_wrappers are disabled on your server or something odd is going on elsewhere in your code.

### extra notes

Where is `$pageId` being set? If it is being passed into your script from the outside world - as in through a URL - I would insist that you use a different way of building your database query. At the very least you should be running some kind of escaping function on the `$pageId` value before you insert it to your query. Otherwise it's quite a security problem. This is because anyone who has access to your URL can obviously modify it, and by doing so they can directly modify your query. The quickest way you can protect your database when dealing with simple IDs is to make sure the value is a number.

```
$pageId = (int) $pageId;
```

Comment: I think the problem might me with the fopen_wrappers. I'm doing this locally via XAMPP. I'll look around and see.

Comment: Odd, everything seems to be fine. The file is readable, it appears as though fopen is enabled and the file also exists. Unsure what's happening. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: fopen_wrappers will only affect when you're requesting remote files, which would occur when using google's logo - but not for local. The only other things I can suggest are that you read thru your error log (make sure there aren't any odd errors there), try a different browser - see what happens, maybe try a different php method like `echo get_file_contents()` just to see if it's intrinsic to `readfile` (which could mean there is a memory or output buffer problem). Also u could test by commenting out the headers, echoing the binary data & saving manually through a modern browser (i.e. not IE).